# Tiffany Framework for Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know about Tiffany Framework for making page curl effects in Android?
This is the [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ)
I need to know how to implement it in Android?

EDIT:
Please dont suggest these links to me

1. [android page curl](https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)
2. [Mystic TreeGames](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl)
3. [harism page curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

Comment: As it is a framework owned by Nemustech http://nemustech.com/wordpress/blog/category/solution/tiffany-solution/ I'm not sure what you are asking. Talk to them to buy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the Link provided by Morrison Chang, I came across [nemustech](http://nemustech.com/homepage/). These people have developed their own [UX framework](http://nemustech.com/wordpress/blog/category/solution/tiffany-solution/) for android. I tried to mail these people but seems to be no reply from them.

It seems its their own thing and we cant use it 
:(

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried Tiffany framework but you may want to look at [this](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl).

*Since you edited your question here's [**another**](http://anettosoftware.co.uk/npc.php) one. It's not open source though.*

Also I would like to point out that although page curl effect looks really nice at first but it's only a novelty feature. In recent trends apps are moving from skeuomorphism to flat design (thanks to microsoft for actively advertising it's modern UI), that is doing the things in more natural way.

You may think that what is more natural than a page curl in book, but you are misunderstanding that reader(the user) is already reading a digital book rather than an actual book, and scrolling and flipping are more natural than a page curl. See [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/what-explains-the-current-shift-from-glossy-uis-to-matte-uis) stackexchange question what I am trying to get at. This is not only for the way you see apps but also way you interact. Also these effects tends to take more resource than necessary( I think it might more than rendering the whole ebook).

For actual experience try reading a pdf in Adobe reader and [pokat reader](http://www.pokat.com/), feel what is more natural on a monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to [harism's Curl Pages](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) because it provides near about the same effect but is for images, So just inflate a layout that you want to view, get the `drawing cache` of it using buildDrawingCache method and set the bitmaps

You can dynamically set it from the on touch event

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know is it actually for you now, but you can look at using the WebView (as it is explained with video you pointed out) and apply one of jQuery Pagination plugins like these: [8 jQuery Book Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/8-jquery-book-plugins/) (I guess, there more preferable are #3, #5, #7 and #8) with a content you need. 
I guess you will kill two birds with one stone:) ---> (1)Easy way to realize your concept; (2)More efficient code.

Or if you found another funny solution, please update your post.

Comment: Used the cache to gnerate the bimap dynamically and replaced it with already existing one to get the effect but image cache quality was not good so used flipboard (https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

Comment: Did anybody get any solution as how to perform pagecurl for webview.If so please post it somewhere.